# Firefox unable to download files

Tags: firefox, kde-plasma

Firefox unable to download any file when I use "Choose destination" option. With "Save to folder" option it's works well.

System: Ubuntu 20.04, KDE Plasma 5.18.5.
Firefox 84.02.

I found many related questions but no one answer help me.
I tried to disable addons, create new profile,
I'm unable to download file even with firefox-dev binary downloaded from mozzila page.
But with chromium I have no problems.
My permissions to download folder:

```sh
drwxrwxrwt  3 biblbrox biblbrox  12K янв 27 20:28  Downloads
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this by installing patched firefox from ubuntu 18.04 repository(this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304442/how-to-use-firefox-from-18-04-repositories-in-ubuntu-20-04/1304485#1304485)